# Custom domain not working correctly on heroku rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, heroku, web, dns

I have a domain on godaddy and i want to put it in action on my heroku application i followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf6GhsVGcTQ) and it worked correctly but the problem is that i can only access my website at `www.example.com` and when i call for `example.com` it takes me to a godaddy page saying: 
`"You've registered your domain.Now put it to work."`
and when i tried `https://example.com` or `http://example.com` it got me error

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `example.com` is an independent domain from `www.example.com`.

What you need to do is set up a static redirect or domain forwarding from `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

You should be able to do this in your GoDaddy's administration panel. Here's a [tutorial](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422).

Comment: It did the work @Mihai-andrei Dinculescu but i can only forward my domain to one address like if i will direct it to http then i cant direct it to https but i want to open my domain in all the dns like weather somebody types www.example.com or example.com or https://example.com it need to open my heroku app

Comment: Domains don't care for http and https. If you want to redirect from http to https or the other way a round you should do it in your Rails app.

Comment: sir can you please explain how can i do that in my rails app @Mihai-Andrei Dinculescu

Comment: @AhmedReza in Rails you can set `config.force_ssl = true` in your production.rb and it will redirect requests to https at the app level. That being said, if you want to use example.com + https then you *HAVE* to use a DNS provider that supports using a CNAME at the apex to the SSL endpoint address. The problem is if example.com is a redirect at GoDaddy they won't have a valid certificate if a request to https://example.com is made.